# Is Dusty the doctor that Royal did malpractice work for?

Tags: character, the-royal-tenenbaums

In *The Royal Tenenbaums*, we meet "Dusty" (Seymour Cassel) as an elevator operator at the Royal Palace Hotel. He seems to have a very congenial relationship with Royal Tenenbaum. Later, Royal asks for "Dr. McClure" to be called to the house to respond to a medical incident. Dusty shows up, in a white coat and stethoscope, and performs some kind of exam, with a diagnosis.

Previous to that, we'd also seen Royal consulting with an unnamed doctor played by Dipak Pallana. This character appears again later, tending to Richie in the hospital.

After Henry reveals that there is no "Dr. McClure at Colby General", Royal is kicked out of the house. On his way out, he mentions that the medical equipment he'd brought in was from a doctor who owed him a favor. He'd done some malpractice legal work for this doctor.

Towards the end of the wedding scene, we see Dusty telling Richie that he has "minor corneal damage", which is comical if he's just faking being a doctor, but maybe it's a hint. Then again, the exam that Dusty did on Royal also could just be comical: it seems fairly stereotyped and superficial.

Is there any background information that indicates that Dusty is actually this doctor that Royal has known for a while -- maybe even really is "Dr. McClure" -- working now as an elevator operator because he lost his license?

Or is it maybe Dipak Pallana's character who provided the equipment, although he seems (based on the fact that he's at a real hospital taking care of a real issue with Richie) to be a legitimate doctor?